# Why are two prepositions here?

Tags: prepositions

In a [blog](http://www.firstpost.com/world/north-koreas-kim-jong-un-orders-further-nuclear-tests-tensions-surge-on-in-korean-peninsula-2671080.html), the heading is written as following:

> North Korea's Kim Jong-Un orders further nuclear tests; tensions surge ***on in*** Korean peninsula

Here in this heading, we have both the prepositions together. Is it okay? If not, then how can we re-write the last line?

Also, I wrote a line ending with 'in Korean Peninsula', but then Grammarly shows an error and indicates of using 'on' instead of 'in'. However, I don't trust Grammarly that much, I would like to know which is the correct preposition?

Answer (score 2):

*to surge on* is a phrase in itself. It means *to continue to surge*. It is then followed by the prepositional phrase "in Korean peninsula".

> North Korea's Kim Jong-Un orders further nuclear tests; tensions **continue to surge** in Korean peninsula.

As you mention, rather than "in Korean peninsula" I would normally use "*on the* Korean peninsula". But it would seem odd in your example:

> North Korea's Kim Jong-Un orders further nuclear tests; tensions surge *on on* the Korean peninsula.

Comment: Is it okay to use two prepositions together?

Comment: Yes it is. There are many examples. Say - the festival was kicked ***off in*** New York City yesterday. That said, any 'phrase' that has preposition in the end can make several examples like that!

Comment: Only the second "on" is a preposition. Doubling the same word (saying "on on") just seems odd to me. Maybe it is OK as long as you put a short pause between them. "tensions...surge on...on the Korean peninsula."

Comment: @user3169 - Doubling a word? I wouldn't say that that is a problem. (Would you say that that *that that* was confusing?)